# Отследить открытие <details>

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка:

```css
.block {
  background: #212121;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="lable">Tree</div>
  <details>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img/img.png" class="ico" width="80" height="80">
        <p class="lable2">ABC</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

Как можно отследить открытие `detalis` и в этом случае изменить `height` у класса `.block`?

Comment: Отследи изменения атрибута `open`

Comment: И кстати у тебя тег не верно написан,  надо `details` -  а у тебя `detalis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но можно и проще...

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block')
document.querySelector('details').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(getComputedStyle(block)['height']);
  block.classList.contains('active') ?
    block.classList.remove('active') :
    block.classList.add('active');
})
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
}

.active {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <details>
    <summary>Пример</summary>
    Привет медвед
  </details>
  <div/>
```

И еще вариант с отслеживанием атрибута `OPEN`

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block')
document.querySelector('details').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (document.querySelector('details').open == '') {
    block.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    block.classList.remove('active');
  }

})
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
}

.active {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <details>
    <summary>Пример</summary>
    Привет медвед
  </details>
  <div/>
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но всё же рекомендация автору вопроса: не используйте этот тег. [details](https://caniuse.com/#search=details)

Comment: @meine, согласен, если нужна поддержка `IE`...

Comment: @meine почему не использовать-то?

Comment: @andreymal, нет поддержи IE, Edge

Comment: @meine IE давно не поддерживается самим майкрософтом, а Edge переписывают на движок хрома — нет никакого смысла ориентироваться на них

Comment: @andreymal, у каждого разработчика/компании свои стандарты, хотите - поддерживайте, хотите не поддерживайте. Это всего лишь рекомендация, нет смысла создавать из-за этого холивар.

Answer (score 0):

Если не использовать скрипты. Тогда для начала необходимо изменить структуру Тэгов (см пример в коде). Далее в CSS пишем: `details[open] .block` и ставим нужные свойства для открытых деталей, к конкретному блоку.
Я привел пример без эстетики. Надеюсь вам понятно.

```css
.block {
  background: blue;
}

details {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details[open] {
  background-color: red;
}

details[open] .block {
  background: blue;
  height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <div class="lable">Tree</div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img/img.png" class="ico" width="80" height="80">
        <p class="lable2">ABC</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</details>
```

Дальше вопрос эстетики) Я имею в виду визуальное оформление. Всё.

Comment: На самом деле данный вариант лучший. Потому что не используется js/jq.